# How to set your main window invisble to show a image as main window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, background-image

I want to try to make a log-in screen for kids to log-in on with just their names. I would like to use a image as login screen instead of a boring normal window. My only problem is that whenever i run it, there is still a frame surrounding the image, and when i set the main window invisible it also makes the image inside of it invisible. 
In the image below you can see that there is still white space surrounding the image, even thought its transparend, and there are still borders around it, how do i get rid of this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your window xaml, set the `WindowStyle` to `None`, the `AllowsTransparency` to `true` and the `ResizeMode` to `NoResize`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="{x:Null}">
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To move border-less window, use this code:

```
// In xaml
<Window ... MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">

// In code behind
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left) this.DragMove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ^^. This is exactly what i wanted , now i only have one more problem, i can't move the bear around, its stuck in its first position :/

Answer (score 0):

I think one modification you have to add to @Dusan, in other ways correct answer, is that windows background has to be transparent and your background picture cannot be hosted in the window but in the child control (e.g. in the `Grid`):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
        WindowStyle="None" 
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Background="Transparent" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"/>    
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I used this methode of getting the image in:

` <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="file:///C:/Users/Joey/Pictures/Naamloos.png"/>
    </Window.Background> `